# node-mysql query attempts to replace my question marks with parameters against my will

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I'm trying to run a simple query with [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/) like this:

```
client.query("UPDATE mytable SET emote='wtf?' WHERE id=5");
```

And I get the error

> Error: too few parameters given

Because it found a question mark and expects parameters. How the heck do I tell it to ignore the question mark!? Escaping it with `\` doesn't work. Passing `['?']` as a parameter is completely out of the question - what if I **don't know** the amount of question marks the query contains?

Currently I'm using a workaround that counts the amount of question marks in the query and passes that amount of question marks as parameters. But what if I were to actually need the parameters for what they were meant to do? I shiver at the thought.

So to summarize - How do I tell `client.query()` to ignore question marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's an unsolved bug: [#118: Client.prototype.format shouldn't treat "?" as placeholder inside string literals](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/118)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
client.query('UPDATE mytable SET emote=? WHERE id=5', ['wtf?']);
```

Edit:

> Passing ['?'] as a parameter is completely out of the question - what
>   if I don't know the amount of question marks the query contains?

I skipped over this. Why would you not know how many question marks the query contains? Why would you have an unknown query with question marks?

Comment: The query is being readied beforehand (not in node), so the amount of question marks in the query is completely variable.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to recreate your scenario, the repeat use of single quotes causes a problem:

```
client.query('UPDATE mytable SET emote='wtf?' WHERE id=5');
```

Specifically I see "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when I try to launch the Node instance.

However, I'm able to run an equivalent query just fine, when I switch the outer quotes to double quotes, like so:

```
mysql.query("SELECT * FROM stories WHERE title='Test?'");
```

For comparison, this is the parameterized version of my query:

```
mysql.query('SELECT * FROM stories WHERE title=?',[req.params.title]);
```

Comment: That was a typo in my question, sorry. Fixed now